# Mail server does not recognize my mail as a valid sender

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, roundcube, vestacp

I am using the ubuntu 18.04 server.

When I am trying to send an email to a **particular user**, then this error has occurred:

```
A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<wishtosend@domain.com>:
550-Verification failed for <mymail@example.com>
550-The mail server does not recognize mymail@example.com as a valid sender.
550 Sender verify failed
```

What is that error?
Is there anything that I can do on my side?

Comment: How are you sending this?

Comment: I am sending this by thunderbird. I tried all ports with server configuration. I set dkim and spf records but the problem is stay.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I follow the steps from [here](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/ubuntu-18-04-iredmail-email-server) and now is working perfectly.